# Hardy and Wright irrational sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, irrational-numbers

A few days ago, I read a proof from Hardy and Wright saying if $a_n$ is an integer sequence and if

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac n{a_n}=0$$

then

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty10^{-a_n}$$

is irrational.

Unfortunately, I can't find the proof again. If someone knows the proof or knows where to find it I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any further constraint on the sequence $a_n$, such as the values being integers? We probably want $a_n\gt0$ for sufficiently large $n$ so the sum doesn't diverge.

Comment: The statement is false if the $a_n$ are allowed to be real numbers: take any such sequence $a_n$ and adjust $a_0$...

Comment: It could also be that this statement is completely wrong or that I forgot something here. But thanks for your answers.

Comment: Intuitively, the $a_n$ grow faster than $n$ so that the $1$'s in the decimal expansion are more and more spaced and no period is possible.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: That is what happens (see my answer). If $a_n/n \to 0$ then $a_{n+1}-a_n$ is unbounded. I think my proof works for $\sum c_n b^{-a_n}$ where $0 \le c_n \le b-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof
I just whipped up.

Show:

If
$a_n$
is a positive increasing
sequence of integers and
$\dfrac{n}{a_n} 
\to 0
$
and
$b \ge 2$
is an integer
then
$S
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b^{-a_n}
$
is irrational.

First,
since $a_n \ge n$,
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b^{-a_n}
$
converges.

Let
$S_m
=\sum_{n=1}^{m} b^{-a_n}
$
and
$T_m
=\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} b^{-a_n}
$.

$S_m
=\sum_{n=1}^{m} b^{-a_n}
=b^{-a_m}\sum_{n=1}^{m} b^{a_m-a_n}
=\dfrac{\sum_{n=1}^{m} b^{a_m-a_n}}{b^{a_m}}
=\dfrac{s_m}{b^{a_m}}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
T_m
&=\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} b^{-a_n}\\
&=b^{-a_{m+1}}\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} b^{a_{m+1}-a_n}\\
&\le b^{-a_{m+1}}\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} b^{m+1-n}\\
&= b^{-a_{m+1}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b^{-n}\\
&= \dfrac1{(1-1/b)b^{a_{m+1}}}\\
&\le \dfrac{2}{b^{a_{m+1}}}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
|S-S_m|
&=|S-\dfrac{s_m}{b^{a_m}}|\\
&=T_m\\
&\le \dfrac{2}{b^{a_{m+1}}}\\
&= \dfrac{s_m}{b^{a_{m}}}\dfrac{2}{s_m(b^{a_{m+1}-a_m})}\\
&= S_m\dfrac{2}{s_m(b^{a_{m+1}-a_m})}\\
\end{array}
$

If $S$ is rational,
then
$b^{a_{m+1}-a_m}
$
is bounded,
so
$a_{m+1}-a_m
$
is bounded.

If 
$a_{m+1}-a_m
\le c$
for some $c > 0$,
then
$a_{m+k}-a_m
\le ck$
or
$a_{m+k}
\le a_m+ck$
or
$\dfrac{a_{m+k}}{m+k}
\le \dfrac{a_m+ck}{m+k}$
or

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{m+k}{a_{m+k}}
&\ge \dfrac{m+k}{a_m+ck}\\
&= \dfrac{m+k}{a_m+ck}-\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{c}\\
&= \dfrac{c(m+k)-(a_m+ck)}{a_m+ck}+\dfrac{1}{c}\\
&= \dfrac{cm-a_m}{a_m+ck}+\dfrac{1}{c}\\
&\ge \dfrac{1}{2c}\\
\end{array}
$

for
large enough $k$
which contradicts
$\dfrac{n}{a_n}
\to 0$.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. It was fun working it out.